# number of query values and destination fields are not the same in windows application using asp.net

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

My Coding is below

cmd = new OleDbCommand("insert into [student$] values('" + txtName.Text + "',' " + txtVehicleNo.Text + " ',' " + txtContactNo.Text + " ',' " + txtAge.Text + " ',' " + txtEmergencyNo.Text + " ',' " + txtPAddress.Text + " ',' " + ddReasonForStaying.SelectedItem.ToString() + " ')", con);

I am getting the **Number of query values and destination fields are not the same**

Comment: what are the columns in the student table?  Your should be inserting exactly the same number of columns or specifying which columns before specifying the values.

Comment: give us the table definition? you can also use the field declaration for the insert as in: 'INSERT INTO student (id, name, surname) values('0001','Test', 'student')'. I would also advice you to use that since it gives you more control.

Comment: Using c # in this way is totally wrong, the parameters are not passed in this way and the query does not scivono in this way

Comment: Can i insert into Spread Sheet